# Error: A strongly-named assembly is required

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Windows forms project (VS 2005, .net 2.0). The solution has references to 9 projects. Everything works and compiles fine on one of my computers. When I move it to a second computer, 8 out of the 9 project compile with no problem. When I try to compile the 9th project (the main project for the application - produces the .exe file to execute the application), I get the following error:

```
'Error 3: A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)'
```

The file location for the error is is listed as "C:\PATH-TO-APP\LC".

I have checked in the project properties and all of the projects are set to build in Debug mode, none of them are supposed to be signed. In the project that is failing, the only assembly that it references that is not in any of the other projects is Microsoft.VisualBasic (a .net 2.0 assembly). So I am at a loss to find what ids causing this error (the file referenced above in the error message - "LC" - does not exist.

Anyone know how I can force the project to accept all unsigned assemblies, or to determine which assembly is the culprit?

The only meaningful difference between the dev environments between the dev environment where this worked and the current one is that the first was XP and this is Vista64. However, a colleague of mine who is using XP is getting the same error.

**Third-party assemblies being used:**

- ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit
- ComponentFactory.Krypton.Navigator
- VistaDB.NET20

All of these are referenced in other projects in the solution which build with no problems, so it doesn't look like these are the problem.

So far I have tried deleting the suo file, Rebuild All, unloading and reloading projects from the solution, removing and readding referenced assemblies. Nothing has worked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just got it to build by doing the following:

There had been a licenses file in the Properties of the project in question. After deleting the file (it was no longer needed) the project was able to build successfully. So it looks like that was the culprit.

Comment: I also needed to remove the <EmbeddedResource Include="My Project\licenses.licx" /> from my *.vbproj or *.csproj files.

Answer (score 27):

### What the error means

*"Strong Name : Indicates that the reference has been signed with a key pair."*

If your current project's assembly is signed, then all your reference assemblies **must** also be signed. **Failure to do so will result in this error.**

---

### How to check

Solution Explorer > References > [Click on the reference in question] > Properties

[image: Strong Name = TRUE]

If `Strong Name` is `true` means *signed*, else the *reference* is not signed and is causing the error.

---

### How to fix

***Method 1*** : Unsign your current project's assembly.

Project Properties > Signing > Sign the assembly (checkbox)

[image]

***Method 2*** : Sign the assembly of the reference project. (**Only possible if you're building it yourself**)

[image: Located in Project properties]

Comment: I am getting this error now: "Failed to grant minimum permission requests. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131417)"

Comment: I've triple checked that my current project is not signed (Method 1). Are there any other reasons that it might still be requiring strongly signed resources?

Comment: If this doesn't work, close the solution ; delete the .VS folder ; re-open the solution

Answer (score 17):

#### Yet another possible cause:

(for desperate troubleshooters)

In **Solution Explorer** window, if you walk down your references list and check each in **Properties** window, seeing property **Strong Name = False** points to potential problem.

Comment: Is there anything that can be done about that?  =-\  If it's false, what are our options?

Comment: @Janet – that was a long time ago, but remember I changed the value back to **true** (probably directly, just by editing the value, if I remember correctly) and that immediately solved the problem. If such a direct change is not possible, then figure out what actions need to be taken to get **true** value there in some indirect way.

Answer (score 5):

I've removed the license file from My Project Folder, and re-build again, it was build successfully.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, not sure if this will help, but if you have access to ildasm, examine the three third party assemblies and check the following:

(I found the following googling on your error msg) Its from another guys post, so ignore the names, but the key is that inside the manifest the line should read ".publickeytoken"  not ".publickey"
Link to this thread is at:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/56e13ab1-4c03-4571-92f1-759081bcc78b/

```
Public Key or Token: ab 1a 81 37 f9 79 0c 88
```

Looks ok, right? That sequence really is the public key token of Reflex.dll.

The problem can be seen if we use the ildasm gui and click on "manifest":

```
.assembly extern Reflex
{
.publickey = (2F 5A 20 3A 86 D3 5F 71 ) // /Z :.._q
.ver 1:0:0:0
}
```

Notice the `.publickey` line.

It should say `.publickeytoken`!!!

The problem is that the Cecil module, when creating the modified assembly, puts the public key token in the public key field (or forgets to turn on some flag that says that thiss is a token, not a complete public key. I'm unaware of the details).

So this amounts to a probable bug in Cecil. I should have used Gael's thing instead. :)

Anyway, now I know that the ONLY problem with the original script (before I moved to Cecil) was that it was putting a reference to a non-strongly-named assembly (Reflex) inside a strongly-named assembly (FXCOP).

So I fixed that now and re-ran my original script and ... viola! It works!!

Answer (score 2):

Check the references section of each project in the solutions explorer... Look for references to third party vendor assemblys Like Infragistics, or Data Dynamics, etc. that might not be installed on the machine where you are experiencing the issue

Comment: See above for third-party assemblies being used. The two from ComponentFactory are built in the solution with no problems. The VistaDB.NET20 is strongly signed, if I remember correctly. But there has to be something in this project that is requiring a strongly-named assembly, right?

Comment: Are any of the strong-named assemblies attempting to reference one of your assemblies that has not been strongly named?  This would cause this error as well...

Comment: Nope - none of the third-party assemblies are attempting to reference another assembly. And all of the other assemblies are also referenced in other project with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

I had been using many third-party libraries (MS Ent Lib) and decided to move a few of the dll's to an 'unused' folder. This gave me the error in question. I believe one of the libraries I referenced actually references another library that needs to sit alongside it (even though the dll does not need to be referenced in your project).

After moving the libraries back everything compiled without this error.

Answer (score 1):

A strange fix for me, but I had just pulled this solution from source control.

Was getting this error, went through most of the answers above, and then deleted the solution and re-pulled the solution from source control.

Worked.

Will only apply to a few, but I guess I was one of the few so there will be more. Not sure what happened the first time, but somehow some assemblies must have had some issues when I pulled them across.

Essentially turn it off and on again.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have to specify your target platform explicitly and set it to x86. There might be an issue with the 64bit build.

Another thing: Do you run VS as Administrator? There are issues with VS2005 when it is not running with elevation on Vista, maybe this strange compile error is one of them.