# Assembly from nuget has strong name but cause build error of 'strongly-named assembly is required'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, nuget-package, strongname

I successfully installed 'LiveCharts.Wpf' & 'LiveCharts' packages from NuGet, I use them in my code but when I want to build the project I get this error:

> Unknown build error, 'A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)

Note that those packages have a strong name. You can see it in the attached image:

[image: LiveCharts.Wpf properties]

Thanks.

Comment: could it be https://stackoverflow.com/a/586938/366064 ?

Comment: No. I don't have a license file like this answer, Thanks.

Comment: Can you reproduce this on an empty solution as well? Because I created a new wpf project, installed the nuget package and added CartesianChart like in their tutorial. This worked like a charm. If this works for you then I'd suggest having a look at your projects build settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what caused this problem, but I opened a new project and installed the packages with 'package manager console' and not from 'NuGet Package Manager' and it's work.

Comment: I had the same problem and followed your advice to reinstall LiveCharts.WPF using the Package Manager Console.
The problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, after publishing and trying to build a newer version with VS2017.
 I switched, in the properties->publish -> application files, for the nuget settings to include.
 From:
[image: default setting in publish]

To:
[image: switched to include]

Comment: My NuGet settings were and are 'include' :(