# How to bypass Twilio nuget package error?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, twilio

I've been struggling trying to get the small sample c# console code from Twilio using my Visual Studio 2017 Pro .NET framework 4.6.1. I keep getting this error message from the Package Manager Console.

> An error occurred while trying to restore packages: Unable to find version '1.0.4' of package 'Twilio'/
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages:Package 'Twilio.1.0.4' is not found on source 'C:\Program FIles (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages'.
> http://packagesource: Unable to load the service index for source http://packagesource.
>
> > An error occurred while sending the request.
> > The remote name could not be resolved: 'packagesource'

Any Idea how to fix this problem, has anyone been through this before or the real problem is with Twilio that is not very friendly with C#?

Thank you guys

Comment: Hi All, I was able to pass the error by manually install the Twilio 5.54 via the Nuget command line, but now when compiling I get the following Warning message "CSC : warning CS8002: Referenced assembly 'Twilio, Version=5.54.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have a strong name." And when I try testing I get the following error message: "Could not load file or assembly 'Twilio, Version=5.54.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)"

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing the latest version of the Twilio package which at the time of me writing this is 5.65. Try installing the latest version and see if that resolves the compilation error. I ran a test on my local machine using Visual Studio 2019 (Community Edition) and creating a brand new .NET Framework 4.6.1 console application. Using the NuGet Package Manager I installed the latest version of the Twilio NuGet package and built the project without error. I also used the code from the .NET Framework SMS Quick Start located [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/csharp-dotnet-framework) and it worked with one of my numbers.

As far as the package issue you may want to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50487710/assembly-from-nuget-has-strong-name-but-cause-build-error-of-strongly-named-ass) and see if that resolves the issue you're having. Note that one of the answers was to create a new application and reinstall the package using the package manager console rather than the NuGet Package Manager.

Comment: Thank you guys I finally got it to work.