# WPF FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly. A strongly-named assembly is required

Tags: c#, wpf

I am doing a WPF .net framework appplication.When i run this code,Exception thrown.

here i am calling UIOrderclass xaml file in AddUiorder.

**UIorderClass.cs**

```
namespace UIorder:UserControl
{
  public partial class UIorderClass
    {
  public UIorderClass()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
//some logic part here
}
}
```

**UIorderClass.xaml**

```
 <UserControl x:Class="UIorder.UIorderClass"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
<Grid>
//some UI components here
</Grid>
```

**AddUIorderClass.XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="View.AddUIorderClass"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
       xmlns:add="clr-namespace:UIorder;assembly=UIorder"

<Grid>
//some UI code here
</Grid>
</Window>
```

**AddUIorderClass.cs**

```
{
  
    public partial class AddUIorderClass : Window
    {
        public AddUIorderClass()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
//code here
}
}
```

Error message is shown a as below

> FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'UIorder, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one
> of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception
> from HRESULT: 0x80131044)

Comment: does your current project assembly is signed ? you can check in Solution Explorer > References > [Click on the reference in question] > Properties ->Strong Name=True

Comment: strong Name = false there. and it is disable too. how can i set Strong Name = true?

Comment: I have added a "strong name key file" in [signing tab] but nothing change

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290980/error-a-strongly-named-assembly-is-required (last answer in the page)